# How to authenticate on SharePoint REST endpoint using appid/appsecret from a power automate HTTP action?

Tags: rest, power-automate

I want to perform some SharePoint Online operation using REST from a Power Automate Flow.

I want to use appid/appsecret to authenticate, as I don't want to give permission to a specific user on the target site (which is actually dynamic). So I exclude the simplest SharePoint HTTP action, and fall back to simple HTTP Request. This works from Insomnia REST client, I can perform the request.

However, from the Power Automate flow, I can't make it work. I have to populate some fields regarding the OAuth flow, but I don't find the correct combination. Here's what I tried :

[image: Try]

What are the values I'm supposed to fill in the action ?

**[edit]** Here are some combinations I tried :

```
{
  "tenant": "eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
  "audience": "https://mycorp.sharepoint.com",
  "clientId": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234@eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
  "secret": "*sanitized*",
  "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
}
```

Outputs: `Unsupported app only token.`

```
{
  "authority": "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234/tokens/OAuth/2",
  "tenant": "eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
  "audience": "https://mycorp.sharepoint.com",
  "clientId": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234@eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
  "secret": "*sanitized*",
  "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
}
```

Outputs : `Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'Failed to extract error details from response content ''.'.`

```
{
"authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
"tenant": "eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"audience": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"clientId": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234@eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"secret": "*sanitized*",
"type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
}
```

Outputs : `Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'Failed to extract error details from response content ''.'.`

```
{
"tenant": "eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"audience": "https://mycorp.sharepoint.com/sites/SoSPDiag20201103-TCE002",
"clientId": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234@eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"secret": "*sanitized*",
"type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
}
```

Outputs : `Http request failed as there is an error getting AD OAuth token: 'AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://mycorp.sharepoint.com/sites/SoSPDiag20201103-TCE002 was not found in the tenant named eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.`

```
{
"tenant": "eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"audience": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"clientId": "5cf00a24-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234@eb8edf0a-AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-123412341234",
"secret": "*sanitized*",
"type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
}
```

Outputs: `{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}`

**[Edit 2]** Here is how I setup the same request from Insomnia, which works, but where audience *isn't* mandatory:

[image: Working request from insomnia]

**[Edit 3]** As a workaround, I can use certificate authentication. It works but has more steps to setup. I also guess, regarding the `Unsupported app only token.` and some community posts, that it's not supported to authenticate using secret...

Comment: Are you getting any error after running this flow? If Yes, can you please post the error message?

Comment: @GaneshSanap: I edited the question to add more tests, and their exact error messages